# How does NSData(bytes:length:) convert [Byte] to UnsafePointer<Void> in Swift?

Tags: casting, swift, nsdata, swift-playground

Playing with raw data in Swift I came across something I don't understand.
**NSData** has a constructor:

```
init(bytes: UnsafePointer<Void>, length: Int)
```

where the first **bytes** parameter is clearly of **UnsafePointer** type.
However, if I pass **[Byte]** object to this constructor, not only does the compiler not complain, but it works ok.
But if I try to cast **[Byte]** to **UnsafePointer**, I fail.
How does this work?

For example (you can try it in Playgrounds):

```
let buffer: [Byte] = [0x00, 0xff]
let data = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: buffer.count) // no error
data.description

var pointer: UnsafePointer<Void>
// comment this line to avoid compiler error
pointer = buffer // error
```

I know I can do

```
UnsafePointer<Void>(buffer)
```

but my question is, what does NSData constructor do implicitly, that I don't have to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift maps its own types to C pointers when you're calling a C function that requires them. Apple has a bit of documentation on this interaction: [Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_11).

In short, when you're calling a function that takes an `UnsafePointer<Type>`, it can accept `nil`, an `inout` variable of that type, an array of that type (i.e., `[Type]`, what you're using), or one of the generic Swift pointer types. A function taking `UnsafePointer<Void>` can take any of those, with no constraint on the type at all, so you need to read the function's documentation to see what it expects/will return.

Comment: This is also mentioned in this blog article (https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6) under "Pointers as Array Parameters"