# On Swift for Mac, data type conversion for BLE

Tags: ios, swift, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a question. I am trying to interface with the Mi Band. Found this code on github and it works well. However I do not understand what is happening with the data type conversion.

```
            var u16 = UnsafePointer<Int32>(characteristic.value!.bytes).memory
```

Which comes from this code block:

```
    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {

    output("Data for "+characteristic.UUID.UUIDString, data: characteristic.value!)

    if(characteristic.UUID.UUIDString == "FF06") {
        spinnerView.hidden = true
        let u16 = UnsafePointer<Int>(characteristic.value!.bytes).memory
        stepsView.stringValue = ("\(u16) steps")
    } else if(characteristic.UUID.UUIDString == "FF0C") {
        spinnerView.hidden = true
        var u16 = UnsafePointer<Int32>(characteristic.value!.bytes).memory
        u16 =  u16 & 0xff
        batteryView.stringValue = ("\(u16) % charged")
    } 


}
```

Can someone explain it to me? Thank you!

Comment: It's a way (or new way in last version of Swift, I don't know) to convert NSData to other values (in our case, they are `int` or `Int32`). Before, it was with `getBytes:length:`.

Comment: @Larme Thank you for your reply. In that case why is "UnsafePointer" used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045762/how-does-nsdatabyteslength-convert-byte-to-unsafepointervoid-in-swift ?

Answer (score 0):

This part gets the address in memory:

```
characteristic.value!.bytes
```

But the return type of `.bytes` is `UnsafePointer<Void>`, so this is then converted into an `UnsafePointer<Int32>` type, which is the Swift equivalent to a C-pointer to a 32-bit integer (`int32_t* ptr;`).

```
UnsafePointer<Int32>(characteristic.value!.bytes)
```

In Swift you get the contents of such a pointer using `.memory` (in C it would be `*ptr`). So the `u16` variable is a value of type `Int32` (the contents of that memory location, interpreted as in `Int32`).

```
var u16 = UnsafePointer<Int32>(characteristic.value!.bytes).memory
```

The next lines mask off all the upper 24-bits, leaving only the least-significant 8-bits of the value, then prints this as the battery percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
  if you have this kind of characteristic :

 <CBCharacteristic: 0x26e42b42, UUID = Battery, properties = 0x33, 
  value = <4d455348 54454348 204153>, notifying = NO>


  then use this type code:
  let value = [UInt8](characteristic.value!)
```